# Java monthly scheduler

Tags: java, datetime, junit

I have small scheduling requirement to
configure batch Jobs with monthly interval.

Say, If the Job start time is Jan 5th 2017 and the interval is 1 Month, It will run Job on the following dates.

> Jan 5th, Feb 5th, March 5th, ....

When the app goes down for a while and when it comes up, I am calculating the next run time as follows.

For Monthly Job,

```
(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(jobStTime, currentTime) + 1;
```

It will return the number of runs so far,

For ex,

> `(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between("Jan 5th 2017", "Jan 20th 2018") + 1;`
>   will return 13.

Now, the next run will be calculated as follows.

`jobStTime.plusMonths(13);`

For ex,

> "Jan 5th 2017".plusMonths(13) will return Feb 5th 2018.

Hope, there is no flaw in the logic.

Now, the problem is with Unit testing.

I have a unit testing as follows to test the monthly Job.

Date jobDate = currentDate.minusMonths(2);
Date currentDate = currentDate.minusHour(1);

Say,

**Test Case 1:-**

the Unit testing is running on "Jan 20th 2018 10 AM  -> currentDate.

The Job date will be "November 20th 2017 10 AM" and the **currentDate for testing will be Jan 20th 2018 9 AM.**

So, now the skip calculation will be,

> (ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between("November 20th 2017 10AM", "Jan 20th 2018
>   9AM") + 1;   --> 2

This is fine and the next run will be,

> "November 20th 2017 10AM".plusMonths(2) -> "Jan 20th 2017 10AM"

**Test Case 2:-**  This is what problematic.

the Unit testing is running on "Jan 31st 2018 10 AM  -> currentDate.

The Job date will be "November 30th 2017 10 AM" and the **currentDate for testing will be Jan 31st 2018 9 AM.**

So, now the skip calculation will be,

> (ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between("November 30th 2017 10AM", "Jan 31st 2018
>   9AM") + 1;   --> 3

The next run will be,

> "November 30th 2017 10AM".plusMonths(3) -> "March 30th 2017 10AM"

So, unit tests are failing when it runs on 31st of the month.

Is there any solution apart from handling 31st in the unit testing code?

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out, but it sounds like a logic problem in your code rather than a unit test problem.  What would happen if the app came back up on January 31st after having gone down on November 30th?

Comment: If the schedule is Jan 31st, it will run on 31st. It shouldnt be a problem. I dont think it is a logical problem, but open to other ideas.

Comment: I'm just saying that if the code actually ran on January 31st, you'd get 3, instead of the 2 that you seem to be expecting.  Other than that, I rarely run tests with curDate, and would rather have known dates in the tests if possible.

Comment: Correction: 30 November plus 3 months equals 28 February, not 30 March. So what is your problem? Your program will think the job ran on January 30, which may be true or not. `LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.NOVEMBER, 30, 10, 0).plusMonths(3)` yeilds `2018-02-28T10:00`.

Comment: For easier testing you may use a fake clock. `java.time` is designed with this in mind. For example `LocalDateTime.now(Clock.fixed(someInstant, someZone))` will pretend that the time in the test is `someInstant` (but of course your code shold work on the 31 of the month too).

Comment: The problem is the same test case fails when running on 31st, but it passes if runs on some other day.

Comment: Does it fail because your production code behaves incorrectly when run on the 31st of a month? Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?